# drupal 6: creating custom modules and reinventing the wheel?

Tags: drupal-6, workflow

The basic workflow of my Drupal site is this:

1. User submits article via the Drupal website
2. site admin approves the article AND needs to associate this article to an upcoming review meeting for committee members
3. Review committee meeting happens and all articles associated with the meeting date is displayed and visible to the reviewing committee members to review.
4. Review committee can only leave ONE comment, while site admin can reply to their comments infinite times.
5. Review committee then votes to approve/not approve the article
6. If approved, site admin publishes the article and it is displayed to the public internet.

So far I am doing everything by creating my custom modules and custom forms via the Drupal API, and it's coming along fine.  For example, I am writing my own comment features, keywords feature, voting feature, etc...  But now my concerns are that I am not leveraging Drupal abilities such as taxonomy, search, keywords, etc...  In addition, I see that there are existing modules that can do some of the stuff I am creating. Am I doing this wrong and reinventing the wheel?  I am more PHP savvy so I am going with what I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I went with creating a new node type.  The reason, I figured, is that I would be able to leverage Drupal's mechanisms of referencing nodes.  If I just create forms and store them independently in tables, then it kind of defeats the purpose.

Also, I dropped Drupal 6 and went with Drupal 7.